# Deploying to was with Docker, using Nginx, Browser --> Not found, the requested resource was not found on this server

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am new to this and I am following this tutorial https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/#static-files . It is teaching me how to Dockerize my Django app.

I have just tried to use Nginx. My containers are up. However,when I try to view my app on safari. It tells me that the requested resource was not found on this server. I think it has something to do with my ports. I am not sure. This is my code below. Thank you for any help you can give.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please add your code to the post's body instead of linking an image? It'd be a lot easier for people trying to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Check your DEBUG status, sometimes if DEBUG=0 in your  enviroments variables testing  show that error. Thats because Django cant load the welcome page for example in production.